# Installing newer version of linux over an older version on a windows dual boot laptop?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub2

I have an Asus laptop, with a recovery partition and windows 7 installed. I installed Linux Mint 13 on it, dual-booting it with Win 7.

Now I want to remove Linux mint and on the same partition space install the latest Ubuntu distribution. I am not too knowledgeable about boot records and Grub. I want some advice about how do I proceed such that my recovery partition and Windows installation are not screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Ubuntu like you normally would but opt for the manual partitioning tool when Ubuntu asks you how you want to install. From here you can either format the partition Mint was on or tell Ubuntu to install over it.

Grub will be automatically installed to /dev/sda during the installation process.

Comment: Are you sure this will still allow me to boot into Windows when required and not harm to ability of the computer to perform a factory reset?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't wipe the recovery partition or the Windows partition and only format and install over the old Mint partition